# Is sync.Mutex needed when accessing different fields of the same struct, but in separate goroutines?

Tags: go, goroutine

I have a struct that has several simple fields in it (ie: int, string, and []byte).

I also have several goroutines that modify different fields within the struct. But each goroutine modifies its own field.

I haven't noticed any issues or hints of race conditions. I then added sync.Mutex into the code fairly easily, and the code ran exactly the same.

But from what I have read, it seems some might suggest to use sync.Mutex in this situation. Is it needed, even though the program runs without errors?

Comment: You can build/test your program with the `-race` flag to detect data races. https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies

Comment: The question is if any goroutine reads concurrently any of the fields that are being modified. If yes you need a mutex else you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat each field of a struct as independent for the purpose of locking. Given:

```golang
type Foo struct {
    stringMap  map[string]string
    strings   []string
    numbers   []float64
}
```

The following is safe:

```golang
foo := &Foo{}
/* ... */
go func() {
    foo.stringMap["foo"] = "bar"
}()
go func() {
    foo.strings[0] = "baz"
}()
go func() {
    fmt.Println(foo.numbers[0])
}()
```

But this is unsafe:

```golang
go func() {
    fmt.Println(foo.numbers[0])
}()
go func() {
    foo.numbers = append(foo.numbers, 123.456)
}()
```

So you would typically want one mutex for each field, or each group of fields which may be modified together:

```golang
type Foo struct {
    stringMapMu sync.Mutex
    stringMap   map[string]string
    stringsMu   sync.Mutex
    strings     []string
    numbersMu   sync.Mutex
    numbers     []float64
}
```

Then:

```golang
go func() {
    foo.numbersMu.Lock()
    defer foo.numbersMu.Unlock()
    fmt.Println(foo.numbers[0])
}()
go func() {
    foo.numbersMu.Lock()
    defer foo.numbersMu.Unlock()
    foo.numbers = append(foo.numbers, 123.456)
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very careful with the Flimzys method! If you want to work with different fields of your structure in the same goroutine and not keep track of the blocking order of the fields, you may end up deadlocked. https://play.golang.org/p/wbgs40UoP-h

The same order of blocking works fine

```
//the same order stringMapMu-->numbersMu
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    foo.stringMapMu.Lock()//lock on stringMap, waits unlocking numbersMu by other goroutine
    defer foo.stringMapMu.Unlock()

    foo.numbersMu.Lock()
    defer foo.numbersMu.Unlock()

    fmt.Println(foo.numbers, foo.stringMap)
}()

//works fine
//the same order stringMapMu-->numbersMu
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()

    foo.stringMapMu.Lock()//lock on stringMap, waits unlocking numbersMu by other goroutine
    defer foo.stringMapMu.Unlock()

    foo.numbersMu.Lock()
    defer foo.numbersMu.Unlock()

    foo.numbers = append(foo.numbers, 123.456)
    foo.stringMap["foo"] = "bar"
}()
```

But the reverse order is ... deadlocked

```
    //reverse order numbersMu-->stringMapMu
go func() {
    foo.numbersMu.Lock()//lock on numbersMu, waits unlocking stringMapMu by other goroutine
    defer foo.numbersMu.Unlock()

    foo.stringMapMu.Lock()
    defer foo.stringMapMu.Unlock()

    foo.numbers = append(foo.numbers, 123.456)
    foo.stringMap["foo"]="bar"
}()
```

Moreover, the locks of individual fields can be implicit and hidden inside the "Set" and "Get" methods. You will operate them in a different order within your goroutines and you will end up with a deadlock = ( I would prefer a single Mutex for your struct if it is not a performance issue.